# Can we capture a screenshot of vim window using Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen-capture, vi

Let's say I have a file called `hello.py`.

```
# File: ~/hello.py
print('Hello')
print('Stack Exchange')
```

I would like to get a screencapture of hello.py when opened in vim editor as the `~/hello.png`.

**Need**
Needed is a script called `highlighter.sh` which can do this.

```
bash highlighter.sh hello.py # should give hello.png with 
                             # syntax highlight
# For example when we open hello.py in vim
# It gives syntax-highlighted code, I need
# screencapture of this tab or window.
# In the end of command these tab or window should be closed.
```

**Usage**

We will have syntax highlighted png files for all the scripts which we can quickview in Mac.

**Updates so far**

```
Open the terminal # or, cd ~
vi hello.py
cmd t # opens new tab
screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to id of window 1') hello1.png  # this captures this command, not the screen of vim tab.
```

Related links:
https://github.com/thismachinechills/pyscreencapture
https://github.com/vorgos/QuickGrab
https://github.com/smokris/GetWindowID
[Take a screenshot of the top-most window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135633/take-a-screenshot-of-the-top-most-window)

Comment: Is the some reason you cannot just use the macOS builtin keyboard shortcut and take a screenshot of the Terminal window? For example: Shift-Command-4-Space > mouse over the target window and click or press Enter

Comment: The intent may be to generate a screenshot programatically, such as from a script, rather than requiring user input.

Answer (score 1):

By combining the built-in `screencapture` with `osascript -e` you should be able to perform the following:

`screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to id of window 1') hello1.png`

If you have more than one Terminal window currently open you'll need to adjust the windowID value.

Comment: Thanks, but It captures the tab of terminal running this given command, not the tab running VIM, and also does not close the tab with vim .

Comment: You should update your original question to indicate that you'd like to capture a specific tab in Terminal, not window, and that you'd like your intended command to also close the window/tab.  In my testing I was able to run this command from a separate window as well as from a new shell after SSHing in and capture the contents as originally stated.